# An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListTopicRules operation: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I got this error when using aws CLI, following the tutorial shows below to configuring the AWS CLI, I can only set up the AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key. Where can I set the security token? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Comment: I am facing the same problem here. At first, I changed the default region and I thought that was the problem, so I repeated the installation and left all the values to the default, however, the error continued to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. It might seem very simple though.
Basically you were following the tutorial literally, which means you most probably input the exact `AWS Access Key ID` and `AWS Secret Access Key` mentioned in the tutorial. 
However, those keys in red are just examples. What you should use are the keys from your own AWS account, i.e. `My Security Credentials`.